# Jenkins : How to restrict building a package after first time

Tags: maven, jenkins

Assume I have module A that depends on modules B, C, D

Now:

- B depends on E which depends on Z
- C depends on F which depends on Z
- D depends on G which depends on Z

When I am building A on Jenkins, I am seeing Z is building 3 times. I was wondering if there is way to restrict Jenkins from building Z after the first time.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using Maven?

Comment: Yes. We are using Maven

Comment: hmm, it's been some time since I worked on such a complex project structure but as far as I recall, Z should only be built once as default behaviour. Do you maybe have any options activated in your pom that could force such a behaviour?

Comment: Which maven target are you calling ? By package, I assume you are talking about a module (maven calls sub projects modules). Are you calling install target for package Z ? iMake sure it is installed on the local cache on jenkins machine.

Comment: Maven goal that I am using 'clean verify' for module A   and 'clean install -U' for Z.  And yes , I am talking about modules. Module Z is mostly about including common dependencies that most other modules use.

Comment: I hope you have parent [aggregation](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Aggregation) for your modules and aggregator should show the modules in order Z, E, F, G, B, C, D, A. To build module A with all dependent modules, you should use `mvn clean install --also-make --projects A` (from your parent pom directory and this will not execute Z thrice!). If the required dependencies are already built, then `mvn clean install --projects A` should work (Which will not any dependent module).